# How to accept the alerts in selenium for android emulator?

Tags: android, selenium

1. I have tried with below coding for accepting alerts in selenium for iphone.It works fine.

2.Is there any method for accepting alerts for android emulator.

```
 caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts",true);
```

3. I have attached the sample image of alerts below.
   [image]

Comment: What you are using? selendroid? appium? or any other???

Comment: I am executing my test cases in saucelab. https://saucelabs.com